# Exclude certain file/lib for building in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Since Flutter web does not support `dart:io` lib yet and there are lots of packages depends on `dart:io`.

During the build for my app i am getting this error

```
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:

app_core|lib/src/blocs/service/user_chat_bloc.dart
mqtt_client|lib/mqtt_client.dart
```

Lets say if i want to build without `mqtt_client.dart` or `user_chat_bloc.dart`. 
Building without this lib wont hurt for web but i want to keep the lib for flutter native. Also there is no clear documentation on how to skip building for those files.

The doc here https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings is also not clear on how to skip certain files

I have tried this in `build.yaml` but no luck

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|app_core:
        generate_for:
          exclude:
            - lib/src/blocs/service/user_chat_bloc.dart
            - lib/mqtt_client.dart
```

Comment: May I know where can be found this build.yaml file?, I want to excludes some file in my flutter project ( Mobile Application not web)

Comment: @UttamPanchasara you have to create it yourself.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have created and added some exclude code, but seem like it not excluding

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it in `build.yaml` like this:

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      exclude:
        - lib/test_driver/runner.dart
        - lib/tools/**.dart
```

More details explanation you can find [at the same article you've linked](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-fix-assetnotfoundexceptions-for-swap-files)

Comment: hello, do you know how to adapt this to ignore packages? and how to ignore them specifically on the web. I'm not seeing that information in the article