# how to exclude a file while building a apk in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-build

While building **apk** for my flutter app I need to avoid from files in building . I have tried by below code in build.yaml but it does not work

```
targets:
$default:
sources:
  exclude:
    - lib/widgets/hotel.dart
    - lib/widgets/hotel_list_view.dart
    - lib/widgets/hotel_list_data.dart
    - lib/widgets/smooth_star_rating.dart
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Some inquiries for your posted question:
Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e., the code to reproduce the problem you describe, as well as a clear description of the Problem: ["It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Furthermore, you could add on what you already try to solve the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude certain file/lib for building in flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188511/exclude-certain-file-lib-for-building-in-flutter-web)

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify it in build.gradle

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '{path}'
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working , do you have any other solutions

Comment: why are you trying to exlude Dart code in a Flutter app ?

Comment: because I'm having multiple client with same sources code so, while building the app I do not what those code which is not needed for another client