# How to ignore package when building flutter project for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-web

I have a project which uses `flutter_libserialport` library on macOS.
I am modifying it to work on web however this library does not work on web.

I am building a web implementation using `navigator.serial` in javascript which works fine.

However when I attempt to build the project for web I get the following error

```
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.2.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/libserialport-0.2.0+3/lib/src/config.dart:25:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
```

This makes sense since FFI is not available on web.

But I don't even need the `libserialport` library on web any way.

How can I get flutter to ignore it?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188511/exclude-certain-file-lib-for-building-in-flutter-web) however it doesn't contain information on how to exclude a package.

It also does not contain information on how to ignore it specifically for web. It seems to just ignore it in general.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an.

Comment: I found it a few minutes ago. it might be what I need.

Comment: okay good just try it

Comment: @Diwyansh I was successful thanks.

Comment: Pleased to help you...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should guard your usages of `libserialport` with the `kIsWeb` predicate like following:

```
if(!kIsWeb){
// libserialport code execution here
}
```

---

I searched a lot as well and didn't find a way you can do that, I think this should be handled by the package itself not the package's users like in `path_provider` for instance.

As a workaround I have created a dummy `libserialport`'s `SerialPort` class for web only as follows:

`dummy_serialport.dart`:

```dart
class SerialPort {
  final String name;
  static List<String> availablePorts = ['dummy'];
  static SerialPortError? lastError;
  SerialPort(this.name);

  bool openReadWrite() {
    return false;
  }
}

class SerialPortError {}

// add more properties and functions as needed
```

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:libserialport/libserialport.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) './dummy_serialport.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'package:libserialport/libserialport.dart';

....
 if (!kIsWeb) {
      final name = SerialPort.availablePorts.first;
      final port = SerialPort(name);
      if (!port.openReadWrite()) {
        print(SerialPort.lastError);
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
    ....
....
```

It's bad, I know :( but it works! maybe you can contact the package author to get more insight and if opening a PR where the interfaces are separated from the FFI implementation so that importing the classes wouldn't break web or something.

Comment: kIsWeb is a runtime variable. The issue I'm having is at build time. I want to exclude it from the build entirely

Comment: Yea, you are right.
It's really weird that when I searched I found nothing but I came up with a really bad workaround I hope it helps, for now, I'll update my answer.